# Limit of $\frac{xy-z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Study the following limit: $$ \lim\limits_{ (x,y,z) \to (0,0,0) } \frac{xy-z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} $$

I'm not sure if this way of proving that the limit does not exist is correct so I'm this is basically for a proof verification.

Approaching $(0,0,0)$ through the plane $z=0$, then the limit becomes

$$ \lim\limits_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} $$

Now this limit does not exist, because approaching $(0,0)$ through the line $y=0$, the limit becomes

$$ \lim\limits_{ x \to 0 } \frac{0}{x^2} =0$$

But if we approach $(0,0)$ through the line $y=x$ we have that

$$ \lim\limits_{ (x,x) \to (0,0) } \frac{x^2}{2x^2}=\lim\limits_{ (x,x) \to (0,0) } \frac{1}{2} =\frac{1}{2}$$

So the limit $ \lim\limits_{ (x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} $ doesn't exist. This means that the limit we began with doesn't exist, correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If the limit does not exist along a direction, it cannot exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the conclusion is correct.

Here's another way to understand it .  . .

By setting $z=0$, $y=0$, and then letting $x$ approach $0$, you are effectively approaching $(0,0,0)$ along the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with parametric form
$$
\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=0\\
z=0
\end{cases}
$$
and by setting $z=0$, $y=x$, and then letting $x$ approach $0$, you are effectively approaching $(0,0,0)$ along the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with parametric form
$$
\begin{cases}
x=t\\
y=t\\
z=0
\end{cases}
$$
so now you have two paths in $\mathbb{R}^3$ approaching $(0,0,0)$, for which the limits exist, but are not equal.

Nevertheless, your reasoning is fine as it is. There's no need to construct actual paths in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I was just showing that it *could* be viewed that way. By slicing $\mathbb{R}^3$ along the plane $z=0$, you can still approach $(0,0,0)$ just as you did, so if the limit fails to exist when approaching the origin in the plane $z=0$, regarded as $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it fails in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if your way is true but you can use:

we may approach (0,0,0) on the track: (z,z,z) so that,
$lim_{z \to 0}\frac{zz-z^2}{3z^2} = 0$

and look at the track: $(z^2,z^2,z)$ so that,
$lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^4 - z^2}{2z^4+z^2} = lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^2 - 1}{2z^2+1} = -1\neq 0
$

and therefor the answer

Comment: actually its the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You can applay [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to solve this limit. In the spherical coordinate system we suppose that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x=r\,\sin(\theta)\,\cos(\phi)\\
y=r\,\sin(\theta)\,\sin(\phi)\\\tag{1}
z=r\, \cos(\theta)
\end{array}
$$
and the relation between $x$,$y$ and z is as follows 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\tag{2}
$$

If we substitute the values of  $x$,$y$ and z by $(1)$ when $r$ tends to zero and the value of limit exists and be independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$, we conclude that the limit exists and in the other cases it results  that the limit dose not exist. Therefore, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy-z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)-r^2\cos^2(\phi)}{r^2}
$$
$$
=\lim_{r\to 0}\,\sin^2(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)-\cos^2(\phi)
$$
 The limit  dose not exist; since it is dependent to paramatrs $\theta$ and $\phi$.

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I haven't got the time right now to look through this thoroughly, but saving this, as spherical coordinates might come in handy in the future!!